# comando python para "pegar" o texto dos campos Qt Designer e salvar no sqlite

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt-5

Boa Tarde. Sou entusiasta e estou iniciando no python. Com o Tkinter eu consigo enviar o texto dos campos para o banco de dados com a função "get()", no gtk,se não me engano, com "get_text()". Gostaria de saber qual seria essa função no PyQt. Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Por favor, edite a questão e adicione um trecho do seu código que nos deixe ver como você nomeia  e acessa os seus campos.

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu campo de entrada for um `QtWidget.QLineEdit`, você obtem o texto com a chamada ao método `.text()`.

Já se for um campo do tipo `QtWidgets.QTextEdit`, você primeiro pega uma referência ao `QTextDocument` associado, e então pode ter todo o conteúdo em edição com uma chamada ao método `.toPlainText()`;

```
conteudo = widget.document().toPlainText()
```

App tipo "hello world" para exibir sempre a última linha digitada na área de edição:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


def update(document, line):
    text = document.toPlainText()
    last_line = text.split("\n")[-1]
    line.setText(last_line)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    manager = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(window)

    area = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
    line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    document = area.document()

    document.contentsChange.connect(lambda: update(document, line))

    manager.addWidget(area, 0, 0)
    manager.addWidget(line, 1, 0)

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sobre esse programa: a linha `document.contentsChange.connect(lambda: update(document, line))` conecta o sinal de mudança do conteúdo do texto com uma função anônima definida no mesmo lugar: `lambda: update(document, line)` - por que os sinais do Qt não mandam junto outros parâmetros. Como no callback `update` quero ter acesso ao document e ao outro widget, o lambda é chamado sem parâmetros, e chama `update` passando as variáveis  a que quero ter acesso na outra função como parâmetros.

Answer (score -2):

def funcao_principal():
linha1 = formulario1.lineEdit.text()
linha2 = formulario1.lineEdit_2.text()
linha3 = formulario1.toPlainText()
linha4 = formulario1.lineEdit_4.text()

```
monitoramento = ""

if formulario1.radioButton.isChecked():
    print("Monitoramento de Saúde")
    monitoramento = "Saúde"
elif formulario1.radioButton_2.isChecked():
    print("Monitoramento de Atraso")
    monitoramento = "Atraso"
elif formulario1.radioButton_3.isChecked():
    print("Indisciplina")
    monitoramento = "Indisciplina"
elif formulario1.radioButton_4.isChecked():
    print("Monitoramento de Saída Autorizada")
    monitoramento = "Saída Autorizada"
else:
    print("Monitoramento de Atendimento Individual")
    monitoramento = "Atendimento Individual"


print("Matrícula",linha1)
print("Turma",linha2)
print("situação",linha3)
print("data_situação",linha4)


cursor = banco.cursor()
comando_SQL = "INSERT INTO ta_alunos (Matricula,Turma,situação,data_situação,monitoramento) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
dados = (str(linha1),str(linha2),str(linha3),str(linha4),monitoramento)
cursor.execute(comando_SQL, dados)
banco.commit()
formulario1.lineEdit.setText("")
formulario1.lineEdit_2.setText("")
formulario1.plainTextEdit.setText("")
formulario1.lineEdit_4.setText("")
```

Comment: Na linha3 não estou conseguindo enviar texto para o banco de dados, estou usando qt desing. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).